# Reading from src/main/resources gives java.nio.file.InvalidPathException on command line (but works fine in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I read the file src\main\resources\input.txt as follows

```
    String abslutefn = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("input.txt").getFile().trim();
    Path path = new File(abslutefn).toPath(); 
    String lines = Files.readString(path);
```

Above works great from Eclipse. But when I build and run from command line it fails

```
mvn clean install
java -cp target\boolean.jar com.xx.yy.zz.App
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:xyz
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at java.base/java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2290)
```

I peek into jar file

```
jar -tf target\boolean.jar
```

I see input.txt file at the root (and there is no src\main\resources)

What can I do to ensure file loads correctly when I run from command line `jar -tf target\stealthboolean.jar` . I am thinking something needs to be done in pom.xml but I am not sure what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Path` and `Files` with resources.

The getFile() method of URL **does not** return a valid file name.  It’s only called getFile() because java.net.URL was written 25 years ago, when URLs usually referred to physical files on other machines.

You can, however, open a resource as a stream, and convert the bytes yourself:

```
String lines;
try (InputStream stream =
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.txt")) {

    lines = new String(stream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Nice and crisp. Requires JDK 1.9 or higher

Comment: Your question uses [Files.readString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString%28java.nio.file.Path%29) which requires Java 11, so I made the same assumption.